# Unable to "add more logins" - caught in login loop

Tags: support, login, openid

I have a self-hosted OpenID provider which I use to log into the StackExchange sites. I'd like to add a StackExchange login to my StackExchange account, however, the "add more logins.." link just switches me between accounts.

Steps, running in private browsing to prevent any cookie issues:

1. I created a StackExchange login using my email address (mail@example.com).
2. I logged into StackExchange using my self-hosted OpenID account, which authenticates me as nicholas-sideras.
3. I followed the "add more logins..." link to [this](https://stackexchange.com/users/login?noauto=true&returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent) page.
4. I click the button to login with StackExchange, and provide my email address and password.
5. I am taken to a page that says

   > You are currently logged in.
   >
   > Do you want to log out and log in with this OpenID?
   >
   > Stack Exchange (mail@example.com)
6. I click the login button, and am switched to the new account that was created with the mail@example.com StackExchange OpenID credentials.
7. So then I try to "add more logins..." and authenticate to my self-hosted OpenID provider, where I am then switched back to my original StackExchange account. "add more logins..." just keeps switching me back and forth between accounts.

(Hopefully this is clear. I'm working with self-hosted OpenID credentials, StackExchange OpenID credentials, this StackExchange account that posted this question, and a StackExchange account that was created when I created the StackExchange OpenID credentials.)

I expected step 4 to add mail@example.com with StackExchange OpenID as a login with my current account. Am I misunderstanding the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrm. Come to think of it, I'm not sure the "add more logins" stuff on stackexchange.com works... I'll take a look at it. On Q&A sites, we currently don't have the option to add a Stack Exchange OpenID as a new credential. I don't really know why; it's on my list of things to figure out Sometime Soon (TM).

In the meantime, your best bet here would be to just create a new site profile (say, here on Meta) in an incognito window using your new SE OpenID, and then [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) to have your two profiles merged.

Comment: Ok, I've submitted a request to merge the new StackExchange account with my existing account. Thanks.

Comment: The '"add more logins" stuff on stackexchange.com' used to work as shown [in this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114704/195914), but I'm getting the same login loop as the OP describes. I consider that a bug.