# "Add more logins" isn't adding more logins, with no visible errors reported

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, openid

I can't seem to add a new login to my account.

My profile currently uses a Google account to log in that is not my default. I'm trying to add my default as a new login, but it's not working. There's no errors, just ... nothing happens.

1. Go to [My Profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) → [Edit profile and settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) → [My Logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current). On this page I see my current login email, plus my contact email.
2. Click "add more logins..."
3. Arrive at [a Stack oauth page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent). Click "Add login with Google":

   [image: "You are currently logged in as doppelgreener. Add another way to log in using any of the following services." A button labelled "Add login with Google" has the cursor on it.]
4. Pick the Google account I want to use from the list:

   [image: A google accounts list with a heading: "Choose an account to continue to stackauth.com". The cursor is hovering over one of the emails, which is covered in a black bar.]
5. Arrive at a "Confirm a new login" page which displays the email I just chose:

   [image: "Confirm a new login: Add a login from Google (email hidden in a black bar). We will automatically link this account with your accounts on other Stack Exchange sites."]
6. Press "Confirm new login", and arrive back on my profile (https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current)
7. Head back to [Edit profile and settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) → [My Logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current)

Expected: I see my original login email, my contact email, and the new login email I just added.

Actual: I still only see the original login email and my contact email. The new login email isn't shown anywhere at all. It's like the entire process just did nothing at all.

I see no console errors on Stack Exchange's side during the process.

I've seen [an old 2014 report that the user kept getting logged out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238732/unable-to-add-more-logins-caught-in-login-loop), but nothing like that is happening here—I'm still logged in the whole way through.

Answer (score 2):

The login is working, but you already have an account registered with that email address. Normally, we would trigger an auto-merge in this case because you've verified ownership of both accounts. However, you are also a member of a Team so you are not allowed to use automatic or self-serve merging. You will need to [contact Teams support](https://stackoverflow.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/26) in order to have the accounts merged together.

It's difficult to catch that scenario to display an error because so many things happen behind the scenes when these situations happen. In fact, many users experience a server error when an auto-merge triggers, because they go on to reload a page while the merge is ongoing in the background.

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot I had created that account.